# Moving Codeigniter website & APIs to new URL with 301

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

We have a domain like xyz.in and we are going to switch to example.com

Our application was developed on Codeignitor framework and we also have a API section running for the mobile apps we have... the api's were like follows...

http://www.example.in/api/v1/createuser

Now if i have to switch to new domain i will move codeignitor to the new domain's host and will change codeignitor configuration 'base url' to our new url so the remaining site will start work with new domain.

Now the question is how to get our example.in visitors to moved to example.com with same parameters they arrive. We have lot of optimized pages on google and google send a good amount of traffic. we want the users to be redirected to our new server and same page they have requested for. For which i found the following piece of 301 code...

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.in [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.in [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

i hope this will do the job. Now my question is the apps that run on top of our API... How does that react ? does this htaccess redirection helps the app requests to be redirected to new domain APIs automatically ? or we have to force users to download our new app with updated new api URL ?

Comment: Try to setup your old domain to reverse proxy your new domain. If it will not work accordingly to your setup, just proxy the `/api` url to your new domain.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to perform something like this:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$  http://example.com/api/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>`